# Pyinstaller numpy. EXE throws error at runtime

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller, astropy

I am having the following runtime problem running an exe file built with pyinstaller:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "astro_scheduler.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\users\nmonte~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-k6m_nn\pyinstaller\PyIn
staller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "source\MainWindow.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\nmonte~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-k6m_nn\pyinstaller\PyIn
staller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "source\Commands.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\WORKSP~1\ASTROS~1\dist\ASTRO_~1\astropy\__init__.py", line 116, in <m
odule>
    _check_numpy()
  File "C:\WORKSP~1\ASTROS~1\dist\ASTRO_~1\astropy\__init__.py", line 110, in _c
heck_numpy
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Numpy version 1.9.0 or later must be installed to use Astropy
[8480] Failed to execute script astro_scheduler
```

This is my freeze:

```
altgraph==0.16.1
astroid==1.6.6
astroplan==0.5
astropy==2.0.16
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.2.0
auto-py-to-exe==2.6.5
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5
bottle==0.12.17
bottle-websocket==0.2.9
certifi==2019.9.11
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.1
configparser==4.0.2
dis3==0.1.3
Eel==0.10.4
enum34==1.1.6
funcsigs==1.0.2
future==0.17.1
futures==3.3.0
gevent==1.4.0
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
greenlet==0.4.15
idna==2.8
iso8601==0.1.12
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.2
macholib==1.11
mccabe==0.6.1
modulegraph==0.17
more-itertools==5.0.0
numpy==1.16.5
pefile==2019.4.18
pluggy==0.7.1
psutil==5.6.3
py==1.8.0
pycparser==2.19
pyfits==3.5
PyInstaller==3.5
PyInstaller-Hooks==20191003
pylint==1.9.5
PyPubSub==3.3.0
pytest==3.6.4
pytz==2019.3
pywin32==225
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
PyYAML==5.1.2
requests==2.22.0
serial==0.0.97
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.25.6
whichcraft==0.6.1
wrapt==1.11.2
```

This is the output of pyinstaller:

```
102 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
103 INFO: Python: 2.7.16
103 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
105 INFO: UPX is not available.
569 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\workspace\\astroscheduler', 'C:\\workspace\\astroscheduler']
570 INFO: checking Analysis
570 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
572 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
575 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
639 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
661 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python27\python.exe
1026 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1
fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_60a5df56e60dc5df.manifest
1029 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1
fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_8550c6b5d18a9128.manifest
1030 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1
fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_f47ed0f6f6564d90.manifest
1032 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1
fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_f480bfaef65491a5.manifest
1422 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30
729.6161_none ...
1424 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc
8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57.manifest
1425 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
1427 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll
1427 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
1427 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcp90.dll
1428 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
1428 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcm90.dll
1786 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1
fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_60a5df56e60dc5df.manifest
1787 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1
fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_8550c6b5d18a9128.manifest
1789 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1
fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_f47ed0f6f6564d90.manifest
1790 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1
fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_f480bfaef65491a5.manifest
1792 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0,
 30729, 6161)
1829 INFO: Caching module hooks...
1836 INFO: Analyzing astro_scheduler.py
5520 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   _xmlplus
5680 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
5718 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
10351 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
12109 INFO: Loading module hooks...
12109 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
12111 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
12111 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
12210 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-httplib.py"...
12210 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
12733 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
12849 INFO: checking Tree
12849 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
12849 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
13011 INFO: checking Tree
13011 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
13013 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
13030 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pubsub.core.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 36, in walk_packages
  File "<string>", line 20, in walk_packages
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pubsub\core\arg1\__init__.py", line 16, in
 <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Should not import this directly, used by pubsub.core if applicable

13182 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
13184 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
13530 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
13626 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
13990 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
14026 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
14032 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
14033 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_certifi.py'
14034 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
14045 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
14519 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_
1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_5926f98ceadc42c2.manifest
14520 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_
1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_ed01d9e4fb230e88.manifest
14872 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.3
0729.6161_none ...
14872 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c.manifest
14875 INFO: Searching for file mfc90.dll
14875 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfc90.dll
14875 INFO: Searching for file mfc90u.dll
14875 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfc90u.dll
14875 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90.dll
14875 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfcm90.dll
14875 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90u.dll
14875 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfcm90u.dll
15261 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_
1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_5926f98ceadc42c2.manifest
15263 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.mfc_
1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_ed01d9e4fb230e88.manifest
15263 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.MFC version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0
, 30729, 6161)
15792 INFO: Looking for eggs
15792 INFO: Using Python library C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll
15792 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[BindingRedirect(name=u'Microsoft.VC90.MFC', language=None, arch=u'x86', oldVers
ion=(9, 0, 21022, 8), newVersion=(9, 0, 30729, 6161), publicKeyToken=u'1fc8b3b9a
1e18e3b'), BindingRedirect(name=u'Microsoft.VC90.CRT', language=None, arch=u'x86
', oldVersion=(9, 0, 21022, 8), newVersion=(9, 0, 30729, 6161), publicKeyToken=u
'1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b')]
15799 INFO: Warnings written to C:\workspace\astroscheduler\build\astro_schedule
r\warn-astro_scheduler.txt
15875 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\workspace\astroscheduler\build\a
stro_scheduler\xref-astro_scheduler.html
16134 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
16272 INFO: checking PYZ
16273 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
16273 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\workspace\astroscheduler\build\astro_s
cheduler\PYZ-00.pyz
17579 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\workspace\astroscheduler\build\astro_s
cheduler\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
17674 INFO: checking PKG
17674 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
17675 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
17695 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
17700 INFO: Bootloader c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Wind
ows-32bit\run.exe
17700 INFO: checking EXE
17700 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
17700 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
17700 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\workspace\astroscheduler\build\astro_sch
eduler\astro_scheduler.exe
17704 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
17714 INFO: checking COLLECT
17715 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
17715 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
17756 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 6161)
22865 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

This is the .spec file I am using:

```
import astropy
block_cipher = None
astropy_path, = astropy.__path__

a = Analysis(['astro_scheduler.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\workspace\\astroscheduler'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[(astropy_path, 'astropy')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['astropy'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='astro_scheduler',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='astro_scheduler')
```

Thanks a lot for your help. I searched for similar problems on StackOverflow and other sites, but none of them seemed to solve mine.

Comment: I have to wonder why you have `excludes=['astropy']`. If Numpy isn't a direct dependency of your script but is only used via astropy then this could lead it to being excluded from the bundle. Also, I believe pyinstaller has some special module hooks for Numpy, and in your `pyinstaller` output doesn't show any mention of them being loaded along with the other module hooks. So while I don't have an exact answer for you at this moment, you want to make sure Pyinstaller is picking up the fact that you need Numpy. You might even try listing it as a hidden import.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install and work with the pyInstaller 3.4 version. Because numpy error also occured to me while working in numpy and pyinstaller 3.5 version